# Android Studio (Java) not receiving sequentially correct Button values

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

I am currently working on a game where players are supposed to solve for X + Y with selection of 3 buttons (1 of which is answer) and a "Next" button to go to the next question (by replacing values of components into the next question's). However, I am not able to tally the answers because my tested selection (Button) is always **testing the values of the next question**

To give a little context, 
*questionCategories* is an ArrayList of ArrayList with different levels
e.g. *questionCategories.get(selectedLevel)* returns ArrayList of different arithmetics

*jumbleOptions* populates 3 buttons with correct and incorrect answers which are housed in *options*

I'm having a situation where when answering Question 1, the shown option values belongs to Question 1, but the tested values (in *test)* are from Question 2.

e.g.
Qn1: 3 + 5 - A: 2, B: 8, C: 4
Qn2: 8 + 2 - A: 10, B: 11, C:12
When I attempt Qn1 on B and click "Next" to go to the next question (and test for correctness), Instead of testing **B:8** my program ends up testing **B: 11** instead. I have tried to Log the captured values of each Button and Question's answer but they are all correct and I am not sure where did I go wrong.

The code snippet is within *onViewCreated*, the first question is initialized to display because of placeholder text in the original element. I'm sorry if the code snippet does not make much sense, trying to keep it short so it's (hopefully) more readable.

```
// Initialize first question to display
questionNumber.setText("Question " + String.valueOf(qnNumDisplay));
questionTitle.setText(((questionCategories.get(selectedLevel)).get(0)).toString());
jumbleOptions(((questionCategories.get(selectedLevel)).get(0)));

do {
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Question q = (questionCategories.get(selectedLevel)).get(numQnAnswered);
            // Increment question number related variable
            numQnAnswered++;
            // Replace displayable elements with next question
            //Question Number
            questionNumber.setText("Question " + String.valueOf(numQnAnswered));

            questionTitle.setText(q.toString());
            jumbleOptions(((questionCategories.get(selectedLevel)).get(numQnAnswered)));

            boolean test = checkAnswer(String.valueOf(q.getAnswer()),
                options.get(SELECTED_OPTION).getText().toString());
            Log.d("Answer Correctness", String.valueOf(test));
        }
    });
    counter++;
} while (counter < NUMBER_OF_QNS);
```

Comment: which value does *numQnAnswered* have initially? I can only see that you increment it if the Button is clicked

Comment: @0X0nosugar the numQnAnswered have an initial value of 0.

Comment: There's a lot of your code  missing so I'm mostly guessing. But it looks like you compare the expected answer of a question with number == [*numQnAnswered* before incrementing it] to the current options (**if** you obtain these by calling jumbleOptions([... with the incremented *numQnAnswered*])

Answer (score 0):

Let's simulate the scenario: 
First question is set up manually, and next question is loaded based on button click. I assume `numQnAnswered` is `0` and you're getting the answer from your `Question` object of `numQnAnswered` th position, right?

```
final Question q = (questionCategories.get(selectedLevel)).get(numQnAnswered);
```

As your codes say so.
Notice here, carefully:

```
// Increment question number related variable
numQnAnswered++;
```

Now the problem however is, the answer is validated inside button click, I think you've forgot the fact that the first question was set up manually... & before checking the answer for that one you've incremented the `numQnAnswered` variable, thus your question is one step behind your answer. Hope it make sense.

Just decrement the `numQnAnswered` variable after the validation of current question.

```
// Initialize first question to display
questionNumber.setText("Question " + String.valueOf(qnNumDisplay));
questionTitle.setText(((questionCategories.get(selectedLevel)).get(0)).toString());
jumbleOptions(((questionCategories.get(selectedLevel)).get(0)));

do {
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Question q = (questionCategories.get(selectedLevel)).get(numQnAnswered);
            // first we need to check answer of previous question 
            boolean test = checkAnswer(String.valueOf(q.getAnswer()),
                options.get(SELECTED_OPTION).getText().toString());
            Log.d("Answer Correctness", String.valueOf(test));

            // Increment question number related variable
            numQnAnswered++;
            // Replace displayable elements with next question
            //Question Number
            questionNumber.setText("Question " + String.valueOf(numQnAnswered));

            questionTitle.setText(q.toString());
            jumbleOptions(((questionCategories.get(selectedLevel)).get(numQnAnswered)));


        }
    });
    counter++;
} while (counter < NUMBER_OF_QNS);
```